# Need help in XSL for DOE (disable-output-escpaing)

Tags: xml, xslt

I have this input XML, in which I want to use the `disable-output-escaping` feature to replace the `&quot;` with a `"` instead in the output XML. I have been trying various things on the following XSL, but to no use - something or the other is breaking in the required `name` tag.

**Input XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<book>
    <name>&quot;test&quot;</name>
    <type>computer</type>
</book>
```

**Transformation XSL:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="book">
        <book>
            <xsl:apply-templates />
        </book>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="name">
        <name>
            <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">
                <![CDATA[&quot;test&quot;]]>
            </xsl:text>
        </name>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="type">
        <genre>
            <xsl:apply-templates />
        </genre>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Desired Output XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<book>
    <name>"test"</name>
    <genre>computer</genre>
</book>
```

**Output XML that I'm getting:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><book>
    <name>
                &quot;test&quot;
            </name>
    <genre>computer</genre>
</book>
```

Can anyone provide some insights on how to get this done?

I have been looking at various sources, but to no use fixing this!

Comment: Note that I don't see any need to transform that `name` element at all, any transformation copying it, like http://xsltransform.net/ncntCSx, should result in `<name>"test"</name>` as there is no reason to escape a quote in element content.

Comment: That's nice, thanks for the sample XSL!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By putting the text in a CDATA in your stylesheet you force it to be treated literally.  If it's not in a CDATA it works the way you want.  There is no reason to have it in a CDATA section in the stylesheet.

Comment: Without the `CDATA` section, I just get a blank `<name></name>` tag

Comment: It works for me using Oxygen/XML 14 with Saxon 6.5.5 and Saxon 9.4.0.6 (XSLT 1.0).  It also produces the desired result with or without disable-output-escaping as long as the text is not in a CDATA section.

Comment: Identified the issue after I've applied your suggestion, I had missed out adding the `<xsl:apply-templates />` tag in the `XSL` under the `<name>` tag.